# Changing email address settings in Outlook, with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, imap, email-server

My client has an email address from a previous hosting provider in Outlook, via Microsoft Exchange.

I want to alter the mailbox settings to use the new hosting provider.

His options do not give the IMAP options.

I am worried about deleting the email account to "add new" and see if it manually lets me, because he does not want to lose the emails in his current folders in Outlook.

What is the safest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Create local mailbox storage](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/how-to-create-a-new-pst-file-in-ms-outlook/) called "archive".
2. Drag and drop all the mail to this new archive. (should have pretty large pst file).
3. Unhook and then hook it up again just to be sure, that you copied everything right.
4. Make adjustments you need.

In general, it is good idea to have free mail box with "copy" to policy. Except for it lowers privacy.

Comment: Not only mails should be moved away from Exchange before data gets deleted there - also tasks, contacts, calendar items in [list view](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/29).

Comment: Thank you. I will take that to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The safest method: [Archive your emails to local PST file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6).

About configuring your new account: [Add an email account to Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b)

For yourreference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/68c3ef9f-c7aa-424e-a284-651c624a2458/imported-a-pst-the-wrong-way-and-now-have-alot-of-old-messages-and-folders-in-the-users-mailbox?forum=outlook

Hope this can be helpful.